# How to do workflow for the following situation

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, visual-studio

Workflow has to start automatically when an item is created in the SharePoint list. After that it has to copy the record and add five times into the same list. Problem that I faced it executing (coping) indefinitely, I am just trying to stop the execution after the fifth time, but I couldn’t is there any possibility achieve this scenario. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you actually require a workflow? Can you use an event receiver? In this case, you can disable the event firing while creating the other items.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that each time the workflow runs it creates 5 copies, which each  triggers the workflow which create 5 copies, which each triggers the ...

You have two options, but both require an extra field:

- Have a field CopyNumber, make your workflow only create a copy when this is below 5 and increment it in the copy
- Have a some field Copy/Source which tells if the item is a copy, make your workflow to not make copies when this field is set and set it in the 5 copies it create

Number 2 is the one that performs best and may also give the benifit of telling which item this is a copy of.